# Creating layout PDFs by iterating feature selection and setting extent

Tags: python-3.x, arcpy

In ArcGIS Pro 2.4, I need to create a PDF page of a map layout where the map frame is zoomed to each row in a feature class. Each feature in this class is a polygon. I'm relatively new to ArcPy so I'm learning as I'm going.

So far I've been messing with arcpy.SearchCursor, to iterate the selection of the features. Inside the cursor, I need to use mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(selectedfeature)) and mf.camera.scale *= 1.05 so the polygon shows its surroundings for context. Then I've been trying to export the layout (lyt) to a PDF somewhere. There are 700 of these polgyons (each labelled as a alphanumerical map page) so it's best to do this with arcpy.

```py
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"G:\ArcGIS Projects\project.aprx")

m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
lyr = m.listLayers("PLSS Quarter Sections*")[0]
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Paper Maps*")[0]
mf = lyt.listElements("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT", "Sewer Sections*")[0]

fc = "PLSS Quarter Sections"
fields = ['OBJECTID']
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
row = cursor.next()

for row in cursor:
    mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(row, True, False))
    mf.camera.scale *= 1.05
    lyt.exportToPDF(r"G:\ArcGIS Projects\output.pdf")
```

It should move the map frame inside the layout to the selected feature, zoom out, and save that  layout to a PDF. All it does it give a TypeError: 1. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Looks like your post got cut off? I don't see a question.  Could you update your post with a question?

Comment: Fixed, thanks! Trying to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

After asking around, ArcGIS Pro has a feature called **Map Series** that lets you make a series of maps based off a certain layer. In my case, it created 700 maps with a single polygon framed in the map frame in my layout. It's also much easier than scripting it by hand.